# More efficient copy of parent bound rectangle

Tags: delphi, paint, firemonkey

[image]
I want to copy as efficient as possible the bitmap area behind a TRectangle (in example with red border). This is the boundsrect from the red rectangle in the parent control.

I have this in my Delphi Firemonkey app:

Getting the whole parent surface to a temp parent TBitmap:

```
 (Parent as TControl).PaintTo(FParentBitmap.Canvas,
            RectF(0, 0, ParentWidth, ParentHeight));
```

and then later on to copy the rectangle I want:

```
bmp.CopyFromBitmap(FParentBitmap, BoundsRect, 0, 0);
```

Of course this is not efficient. I want to copy the rectangle in 1 pass or at least I don't want to paint the whole parent into a temp TBitmap.

Do you know an efficient way? Please tell.

I created a TFrostGlass component which has the complete source in it. You can see/download it over here: https://github.com/Spelt/Frost-Glass

The copy bitmap code is in: FrostGlass.pas

Comment: not clear what you want, why not imediatly gave the bmp.canvas ? you have also the function TmyControl.MakeScreenshot

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question, hope its clear now.  The MakeScreenShot will not work because the control only paints the red border hence the screenshot will only contain the red border.

Comment: Call PaintTo with negative offsets? Instead of painting to (0, 0) in the target canvas, paint to (-control.Left, -control.Top).

Comment: Thanks Rob but that will still paint the whole parent control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `PaintTo` does not allow painting only part of the control. However, as @Rob Kennedy mentioned, you can control where on your target Bitmap the content ends up by modifying the offsets.

In addition, when calling `BeginScene` before the call to `PaintTo`, you can set the `ClipRects` parameter, which means that only this part of the Canvas will be updated. This is necessary if your target Bitmap is larger than `BoundsRect`, because otherwise you would also paint the area around it.

```
procedure PaintPartToBitmap(Control: TControl; SourceRect, TargetRect: TRect; Bitmap: TBitmap);
  var ClipRects: TClipRects;
      X, Y: Single;
begin
  ClipRects := [TRectF.Create(TargetRect)];
  if (Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene(@ClipRects)) then
    try
      X := TargetRect.Left - SourceRect.Left;
      Y := TargetRect.Top - SourceRect.Top;
      Control.PaintTo(Bitmap.Canvas, RectF(X, Y, X + Control.Width, Y + Control.Height));
    finally
      Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: The ClipRects does shaves of a lot. Like almost 50%.  Modifying the offsets is not working properly yet.

Comment: The code I posted works fine for the test case I had. If it's not working for you, you probably need to post some of your code, otherwise it's hard to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: I'm using it in a blur component project which I will open source. I expect that next weekend the first beta will be published to github. I'll be in touch.

Comment: You can see/download it over here: https://github.com/Spelt/Frost-Glass

The copy bitmap code is in: FrostGlass.pas